# Calling itertools.product with unkown number of args

Tags: python

I hope this is a easy one.

Is there any possiblity to call itertools.product with a yet (not hardcoded) not knwon number of arguments?

Something like this:

`itertools.product(x[0],x[1],x[2],....)`

and the dimension of x can't be hardcoded

Thanks!

Comment: why not `itertools.product(x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
itertools.product(*x)
```

i.e. we [unpack the argument list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
itertools.product(*x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Lookup [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c= [a,b]

itertools.product(*c)
```

You can pass array of arguments using *